# Syntax for Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead data-source

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a PHP array that I want to use to pre-populate a Twitter Bootstrap typehead, however I'm not sure of the syntax.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="[<?php echo '\''.implode("','", $staff).'\''; ?> ]">
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: Try removing the space between '?>' and the ']', just a guess

Comment: You have to `json_encode()` the output before echo-ing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `json_encode()`:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="<?php echo json_encode($staff);?>">
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! This works great - with one slight modification: It worked when I used single quotes, not double. Eg. data-source='<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>'

Comment: Wouldn't you need `htmlentities` in order to safely put things in an attribute ? Making `<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($staff)); ?>` (which BTW explains the wrong need for single quotes)

Comment: Yup, definitely need the double quotes. Seems like a bootstrap bug or oversight.